# content_tag, oddly nested, rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, nested, helper, content-tag

Trying to create the below using content_tag:

```
<p><span class="field-label">Address: </span><%= @patient.address1 %></p>

<%= content_tag :p, @patient.address1 do %>
  <%= content_tag :span, "Address: ", :class => 'field-label'%>
<%end%>
```

This returns:

```
<p><span class='field-label>Address: </span></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html#method-i-content_tag), if you use the block format then the second argument becomes the options. Ie. you can't mix the content as a parameter and the content as a block.  So to solve this you need to put your `@patient.address1` within the block:

```
<%= content_tag :p do %>
  <%= content_tag :span, "Address: ", :class => 'field-label' %>
  <%= @patient.address1 %>
<% end %>
```